# java.io.IOException when executing Runtime.getRuntime().exec() on 64bit Server 2088

Tags: java, io, ioexception, win32-process

I am getting an error while executing this code:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("%windir%\\system32\\RunDll32.exe shell32.dll,ShellExec_RunDLL  \"" + "C:\\test\\testcloud.txt" + "\\\"");
```

Error is:

```
java.io.IOException: CreateProcess: %windir%\system32\RunDll32.exe shell32.dll,ShellExec_RunDLL "C:\test\testcloud.txt\" error=2
    at java.lang.Win32Process.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Win32Process.<init>(Win32Process.java:66)
    at java.lang.Runtime.execInternal(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:551)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:418)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:361)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:325)
    at com.hoc.ejems2.client.frames.JDiaAttachments.loadFile(JDiaAttachments.java:666)
```

It was running properly on Winserver 2003.

Comment: Obviously `%windir%` is not expanded as you would expect (This expansion is done in `cmd.exe`, so you have to get the windir from somewhere else)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. It was working in Server 2003. I tried with full path e.g. C:\\Windows\\... and it works. Thanks again.